# What can I do if R is still using a lot of memory after I have removed all objects in my global environment, and run the garbage collector?

Tags: r, memory-management

After doing a lot of data munging using `dplyr` and database connections I discovered that my R session connected to my Rstudio instance was using a lot of memory (6 GB) that I didn't think it needed. So I went ahead and did `rm(list = ls(all = T))`, followed by `gc()`. The amount of memory used by `ression.exe` did not change significantly. At this point I killed the process and restarted it from Rstudio, and the memory usage issue disappeared. Are there alternatives short of killing the process from the Windows task manager?

Comment: i care because I have another R session extracting a different block of the database using the same commands, and that extract is already up to using 12 GB of ram and counting. As I have a limited amount of ram it is likely that not freeing this memory will lead to memory issues in a few hours.

Comment: I'd expect R to release the memory when the OS requests it. But I have no idea what you are actually doing and if proper clean-up is done (e.g., closing the database connection when it's no longer needed). And of course, there is always the possibility of bugs.

Comment: Possibly relevant https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14611 ; but, you're on Windows so I have no idea if you can work with https://rforge.net/mallinfo/ effectively on such a crippled operating system.